# Calculating total monthly cumulative number of Order

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the total monthly cumulative number of order. I have 2 columns OrderDate and OrderId.I cant use a list to find the cumulative numbers since data is so large. and result should be year_month format along with cumulative order total per each months.

```
orderDate                OrderId
2011-11-18 06:41:16      23
2011-11-18 04:41:16      2
2011-12-18 06:41:16      69
2012-03-12 07:32:15      235
2012-03-12 08:32:15      234
2012-03-12 09:32:15      235
2012-05-12 07:32:15      233

desired Result

Date                     CumulativeOrder
2011-11                  2
2011-12                  3
2012-03                  6
2012-05                  7
```

I have imported my excel into pycharm and use pandas to read excel
I have tried to split the datetime column to year and month then grouped but not getting the correct result.

```
df1 = df1[['OrderId','orderDate']]
df1['year']  = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['orderDate']).year
df1['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['orderDate']).month
df1.groupby(['year','month']).sum().groupby('year','month').cumsum()
print (df1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes, then to months period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), add new column by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and last remove duplicates with keep last dupe by column `Date` and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
import numpy as np

df1['orderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['orderDate'])
df1['Date'] = df1['orderDate'].dt.to_period('m')
#use if not sorted datetimes
#df1 = df1.sort_values('Date')
df1['CumulativeOrder'] = np.arange(1, len(df1) + 1)
print (df1)
            orderDate  OrderId    Date  CumulativeOrder
0 2011-11-18 06:41:16       23 2011-11                1
1 2011-11-18 04:41:16        2 2011-11                2
2 2011-12-18 06:41:16       69 2011-12                3
3 2012-03-12 07:32:15      235 2012-03                4

df2 = df1.drop_duplicates('Date', keep='last')[['Date','CumulativeOrder']]
print (df2)
     Date  CumulativeOrder
1 2011-11                2
2 2011-12                3
3 2012-03                4
```

Another solution:

```
df2 = (df1.groupby(df1['orderDate'].dt.to_period('m')).size()
          .cumsum()
          .rename_axis('Date')
          .reset_index(name='CumulativeOrder'))
print (df2)
     Date  CumulativeOrder
0 2011-11                2
1 2011-12                3
2 2012-03                6
3 2012-05                7
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But it is not correctly calculating the cumulative number.

Comment: @Erhan - Why do you think? Not correctly working with real data? Can you explain more?

Comment: sorry my mistake i have updated the desired result. I am looking for cumulative number.

Comment: @Erhan - OK, can you explain why `2,3,4` ?

Comment: for 2011 - 11 there are 2 orders. and 2011-12 only 1 which makes total 3 and 2012-03 another one which makes total 4

Comment: @Erhan - Can you check now?

Comment: I got two errors np.arange  and KeyError: "['CumulativeOrder'] not in index"

Comment: @Erhan - A bit changed solution, can you test now?

Comment: @Erhan - Maybe missing `import numpy as np`

Comment: I ran the code after importing the numpy. my cumulative numbers not showing me monthy total it is only increment number for each orderid and associated date

Comment: @Erhan - So I dont understand it, can you create more rows with data samples -e.g. add 5 with expected output? This solution working with sample data perfectly, but maybe need something else.

Comment: @Erhan - Thank you, but both solutions working nice.

Comment: your second solution is correct! but how do you change the name of orderDate to Date? Can you also export the result into excel? Thank you! I really appreciated your help.